# Have a Dell Dimension 2400 (Installed Ubuntu 13.04) after install and login, I get a purple screen

Tags: installation, unity, 13.04, compiz, xorg

I am a fairly new user to Ubuntu.  As stated in the title, I have a Dimension 2400 that I put 13.04 on.  Everything seemed to go perfectly, once I booted it up I got to my login, and then *Boom, nothing happens, all I see is my mouse and wallpaper.  I have done most of what has been said already in the forums:

- Remove your xorg.conf

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  ```
- Reinstall xorg completely

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64

  sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
  ```
- Reboot

  ```
  sudo reboot

  dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
  unity --reset-icons &disown

  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  ```

I have also tried this:

> Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in.
>
> Install the jibby you'll need to configure the settings by running
>   this:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> ```
>
> Then run it by doing this:
>
> ```
> export DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
> ```
>
> The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on
>   (otherwise it won't have a clue).
>
> Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 (or Ctrl+Alt+F8 sometimes) to get back to the
>   graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings
>   Manager screen sitting there.
>
> Find the Unity plugin. Enable it.
>
> Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have
>   to restart. You can do that by going back to TTY1 and running sudo
>   reboot.

And still nothing works. Every time I log in, it's still the same screen.

*During using ccsm I can see the unity plugin, but it dosen't have a checkmark next to it.  I have to open it up, to then try and enable it.  But it never gets enabled.

Additionally I have tried to run this command just for it to say *Command not found* yet I can browse to the exact spot it's in.

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Also when I run `echo "$DESKTOP_SESSION"` it comes back with `ubuntu`, which means unity 3d should be running.

Please help, at this point I am so lost, and just want to go back to running Windows.

This is what my screen looks like after login. Nothing is there:

[image]

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have? Also, it's strange that `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` returns *Command not found*. What about `sudo apt-get install unity`? Is this the first time you have tried to boot the machine after installation?

Comment: yes, this is the first time booting.  as for the possible fix, I have tried every step in that link, and nothing works.  *Again if u read what I posted it states the same steps I have tried. :(

Comment: As for my video card running a lspci |grep VGA returns:
VGA Compatible Controller: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Intergrated Graphics Device (rev 01)

Comment: Unity is installed, running the apt-get install unity comes back saying Unity is already at the newest version.

As for the download, I downloaded 13.04 from Ubuntu's site, then burned it as a ISO (DVD) then when that didn't work, I figured it was a bad dvd/iso burn, so I made a bootable USB with 13.04 on it and Installed it that way.  

Does Ubuntu had Integrated video cards?  Is this why it's flaking out?

Comment: really strange error at startup (after I login) 

Sorry, Ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error.
If u notice further problems, try restarting the computer.
ExecutablePath
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test